# Copy entire template folder from puppet module

Tags: puppet, templates

I'm looking for the syntax to copy an entire templates directory inside a puppet module. (Eg: templates/webconfig/file1.erb, templates/webconfig/config/file2.erb)

I tried to copy in below syntax:

```
file {"$http_home_dir/webconfig":
                        ensure => "directory",
                        owner => "$http_user",
                        group => "$http_group",
                        content => template("webconfig"),
                        recurse => true,
                        require => File["$http_home_dir"];
                }
```

It doesn't worked. When i tried to use wildcard like below also, it didn't worked.

```
content => template("webconfig/*.erb"),
```

Is there anything specific I'm missing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only copy files wholesale using the `source` parameter, which copies files as-is. The only way you can copy multiple templates is to use multiple `file` resources.

A way of shortening the amount of code you need is using a `define` resource type. For example, using Puppet 4 strict typing and the splat operator:

```
define myclass::webconfig (
  String $file_path,
  Hash   $attributes,
  String $template_path,
) {
  file { $file_path:
    ensure  => file,
    content => template("${template_path}/${name}.erb"),
    *       => $attributes,
  }
}
```

Which can be used as:

```
file { $http_home_dir:
  ensure => directory,
  owner  => $http_user,
  group  => $http_group,
}

myclass::webconfig { 'myfile':
  template_path => 'webconfig',
  file_path     => "${http_home_dir}/webconfig",
  attributes    => {
    owner   => $http_user,
    group   => $http_group,
    require => File[$http_home_dir],
  }
}
```

Which will place a file at `$http_dir/webconfig/myfile` with the contents of template `webconfig/myfile.erb`.

You can also pass an array of file names, like so:

```
$my_files = [
  'myfile',
  'myotherfile',
  'mythirdfile',
  'foobarfozbaz'
]

file { $http_home_dir:
  ensure => directory,
  owner  => $http_user,
  group  => $http_group,
}

myclass::webconfig { $my_files:
  template_path => 'webconfig',
  file_path     => "${http_dir}/webconfig",
  attributes    => {
    owner   => $http_user,
    group   => $http_group,
    require => File[$http_home_dir],
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Craig Is the above scenario possible in Puppet 3.8?

Comment: Puppet 3 is EOL - it may be possible in Puppet 3.8 with `--parser future` but YMMV. It's guaranteed to with with Puppet 4.